# Custom Url android from browser address bar not working

Tags: android, intentfilter, custom-url

I have implemented the Android Custom URl scheme and it works fine when I send the link that I want to open as a mail and then click on it.

It does not work when I type the same address in the address bar of my Mobile Browser which in turn gives a page not found error.
This is my intent-filter for the same -

```
 <intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myappname.com"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Is there something else that I need to specify for making http://myappname.com open if I type it in a web browser. Is it the case that some phones/browsers do not support such behavior? Or is this not possible at all?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: What browser are you using??

Comment: currently, I am using the default browser for Samsung Galaxy S2 Duos.

Comment: You might want to check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568792/oauth-and-custom-scheme-result-in-a-err-unknown-url-scheme-in-chrome/15601063#answer-15601063